# How do I kill Anti-Fairies?

Tags: zelda-link-to-the-past

According to ZeldaDungeon.net, these are Anti-Fairies:

[image: Anti-Fairy]

The [site](http://www.zeldadungeon.net/Zelda03-a-link-to-the-past-enemies.php#Anti-Fairy) says they can be destroyed by sprinkling magic powder on them. How do I do that? I'm toward the end of the Eastern Temple, just got the bow. Or am I not supposed to be able to kill them yet, and should just dance around them for now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the Magic Powder from the witch's house north of Kakariko (before you enter the Eastern Palace):

> Head back to the main part of Kakariko Village and go all the way up and out of the village. Head right to the next screen. Continue going right to the next screen. Keep going right another screen. Pass through the graveyard to the next screen. Go down a screen and cross the bridge. After the bridge go up a screen after killing the enemies and cutting through the bushes. Make a right here. Go up and give the mushroom to the witch just outside of the shop. Afterwords, head left a screen and return back to the witch. Go inside the shop and the magic powder will be waiting for you. Talk to the guy in there to fill up your hearts. Exit the shop. <sub>([source](https://www.zeldadungeon.net/Zelda03Walkthrough02.php))</sub>
>
> [image]

Comment: Oh, I guess I didn't look hard enough. Awesome, thanks!

Comment: No, it's easy to miss